# Mac identifies itself incorrectly on network

Tags: macos, networking, mac, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 computer and a Mac OSX (newest OS) computer which I am trying to connect over network at home. Currently they can not communicate at all.

In Windows 10, the Mac identifies itself as "MACBOOKPRO-553B". However, in OSX sharing, I have selected computer name "MAC-LAPTOP-SHARE" (MAC-LAPTOP-SHARE.local) and chosen a folder. I have enabled both SMB and AFP and also tried with SMB alone.

If I try connect from OSX to one of my Windows shared folders... Well, I can't even see the Windows 10 computer (althouth other Windows computers on my network can)

What I am personally most confused about is the fact that the OSX name identification is wrong. That is just plain weird, and I am thinking that solving this could potentially solve the rest as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this could be related to your Mac's name setup. I was recently seeing odd values when in Terminal so manually setting my hostname worked for me. You might need to set your HostName or ComputerName or LocalHostName

**Find out your current hostname...**

- Open the Terminal application on your Mac
- Type `hostname` and press enter to get the current hostname for your Mac

**Set a new one...**

- Still in terminal run these commands one at a time and test to see if they work

  - `sudo scutil --set ComputerName "MAC-LAPTOP-SHARE"`
  - `sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "MAC-LAPTOP-SHARE.local"`
  - `sudo scutil --set HostName "MAC-LAPTOP-SHARE"`
- Flush the DNS cache after each one by running: `dscacheutil -flushcache`
- Restart your Mac.

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Well, it kinda helped! Nit completely though. Windows now shows the new name as well as the old selected one as well as "MACBOOKPRO-553B" where it before only show "MACBOOKPRO-553B". I guess it is because they are somehow remembered in cache and I will try restart Windows to see. Howeber, if I doubleclick the new name in Windows Network I get error "Windows can not access" --- even though I in OS X Sharing have setup a shared folder everyone has read access to.

Answer (score 1):

The name `MACBOOKPRO-553B` likely originates from the NetBIOS field under `System Preferences > Network > Advanced... > WINS`, given that the default value is frequently the device type plus characters appended to it (up to a total length of 15 characters).

It is separate from the Computer Name you set in `System Preferences > Sharing`.

Changing it there will change the string that you are seeing in Windows 10.

Comment: Actually it appears my OS X keeps values the same between thw two configuraion places. 

-- If I first edit "System Preferences > Sharing" and then  open "System Preferences > Network > Advanced... > WINS" it shows the name i just selected (and to the right of it says "xxx is currently being used" where xxx is the name seleted in sharing and also shown in WINS)

-- It should be set I have also filled "WORKGROUP" in WINS setup tp match what I use in Windows